# Access `req` during nextauth signin callback

Tags: next.js, next-auth

Is it possible to access the `req` parameter during the signin callback?
I need to check and log the user's ip during the sign in attempt.

i have followed the advanced initialization process, however, i can't seem to be able to access the session during signin callback.

from docs:

```js
callbacks: {
  async signIn({ user, account, profile, email, credentials }) {
    const isAllowedToSignIn = true
    if (isAllowedToSignIn) {
      return true
    } else {
      // Return false to display a default error message
      return false
      // Or you can return a URL to redirect to:
      // return '/unauthorized'
    }
  }
}
```

i have added the ip like this

```js
export default async function auth(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  
  const ip= req.socket.remoteAddress

  return await NextAuth(req, res, {
    ...
    callbacks: {
      session({ session}) {

        session.ip= ip
        return session
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Can you not access the `ip` variable inside `signIn` like you're doing inside `session`?

Comment: I'm trying something like this: https://github.com/rexfordessilfie/next-auth-account-linking#how-it-works

Answer (score 0):

`req` parameter is not passed to the `signIn` callback. This is the typescript signature of `signIn`. From npm repo:

```
signIn: (params: {
    user: User | AdapterUser;
    account: A | null;
    /**
     * If OAuth provider is used, it contains the full
     * OAuth profile returned by your provider.
     */
    profile?: P;
    /**
     * If Email provider is used, on the first call, it contains a
     * `verificationRequest: true` property to indicate it is being triggered in the verification request flow.
     * When the callback is invoked after a user has clicked on a sign in link,
     * this property will not be present. You can check for the `verificationRequest` property
     * to avoid sending emails to addresses or domains on a blocklist or to only explicitly generate them
     * for email address in an allow list.
     */
    email?: {
        verificationRequest?: boolean;
    };
    /** If Credentials provider is used, it contains the user credentials */
    credentials?: Record<string, CredentialInput>;
}) => Awaitable<string | boolean>;
```